How to stop seeing throught the object
So I'm following a tutorial about topologizing a character and I see throught the object im doing the topology for. The tutorial doesn't specify anything about it and its quite infuriating when i snap the vertices. Any help please?


Hello, could you please elaborate, where do you see through?

So, my topology is supposed to snap on the surface of the hand, But it doesn't do that because, as you can see in the wrist area, it shows me the inside of the palm (that applies to every position i look at ) .And so when i try to snap a vertice on the back of the hand, it goes to the palm. I'm sorry for the description, but english is not my first language. I will edit the post and put another picture with the vertice.
